# Getting error at Iterator while reading from excel sheet

Tags: java

Even though I have imported

```
import org.apache.poi.ss.usermodel.Cell;
import org.apache.poi.ss.usermodel.Row;
```

I am getting error at part

`Iterator<Cell> cellIterator=row.cellIterator();`

Here is my full code

```
import java.io.File;
import java.io.FileInputStream;
import java.io.FileOutputStream;
import java.util.Map;
import java.util.Set;
import java.util.TreeMap;

import java.util.Iterator;
import org.apache.poi.ss.usermodel.Cell;
import org.apache.poi.ss.usermodel.Row;
//import org.apache.poi.hssf.record.formula.functions.Cell;
//import org.apache.poi.hssf.record.formula.functions.Row;
import org.apache.poi.xssf.usermodel.XSSFSheet;
import org.apache.poi.xssf.usermodel.XSSFWorkbook;

public class UploadExcel {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        try {
            FileInputStream file = new FileInputStream(new File("C:\\Documents and Settings\\admin\\Desktop\\imp data\\howtodoinjava_demo.xlsx"));

            //Create Workbook instance holding reference to .xlsx file
            XSSFWorkbook workbook = new XSSFWorkbook(file);

            //Get first/desired sheet from the workbook
            XSSFSheet sheet = workbook.getSheetAt(0);

            //Iterate through each rows one by one
            Iterator<Row> rowIterator = sheet.iterator();

            while (rowIterator.hasNext())
            {
                Row row = rowIterator.next();

                //For each row, iterate through all the columns
                Iterator<Cell> cellIterator=row.cellIterator();

                while (cellIterator.hasNext()) 
                {
                     Cell cell = cellIterator.next();

                     //Check the cell type and format accordingly
                     switch (cell.getCellType()) 
                     {
                         case Cell.CELL_TYPE_NUMERIC:
                         System.out.print(cell.getNumericCellValue() + "\t");
                         break;
                         case Cell.CELL_TYPE_STRING:
                         System.out.print(cell.getStringCellValue() + "\t");
                         break;
                     }
                 }

                 System.out.println("");
             }

             file.close();
         } catch (Exception e) {
             e.printStackTrace();
         }
     }
 }
```

The error which i am getting is:

```
Type mismatch: cannot convert from java.util.Iterator<org.apache.poi.ss.usermodel.Cell> to java.util.Iterator<org.apache.poi.hssf.record.formula.functions.Cell>
```

Could you please help me with this.

Comment: This works for me, using `poi-3.16.jar`, `poi-ooxml-3.16.jar`, `poi-ooxml-schemas-3.16.jar`. What version are you using?

Comment: I am using 3.7 .. Should I have all the jars of 3.16?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You also need this dependency for xssf:

```
<dependency>
  <groupId>org.apache.poi</groupId>
  <artifactId>poi-ooxml</artifactId>
  <version>3.16</version>
</dependency>

<dependency>
  <groupId>org.apache.poi</groupId>
  <artifactId>poi</artifactId>
  <version>3.16</version>
</dependency>

<dependency>
  <groupId>org.apache.poi</groupId>
  <artifactId>poi-ooxml-schemas</artifactId>
  <version>3.7</version>
</dependency>
```

If you don't get compile errors now it means you have this dependency from somewhere else, likely your RiverBoat project exposes an older/incompatible version. So either you need both poi dependencies in this pom, or none (as both may be exposed by RiverBoat).